# How to make a Flash Video start playing on MouseOver, and stop on MouseOut

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-3

I'm wondering how I can make a Flash start playing a video on MouseOver, and stop playing on MouseOut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've imported your video libraries and `myVideo` is the instance name of your video

```
myVideo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, playMovie);
myVideo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, stopMovie);

function playMovie(event:MouseEvent):void {
    myVideo.play();
}
function stopMovie(event:MouseEvent):void {
   myVideo.stop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this!!! regarding this though, I would just add this code to the actions panel for "myVideo"?

Comment: Depending on how you're set up, you could put in the main timeline inside of an `actions` layer.